# Optimal amount of data to return for d3js visualizations

Tags: json, html, performance, charts, d3.js

We are using d3.js to create interactive reports and data visualizations. Bringing back more data on initial load allows richer visualizations and more interaction. However, this takes time.

Could anyone offer their experiences on what they have found provides a good balance of interaction with speed of load time? I *know* this will vary significantly by type of visualization. However a general range would be nice (e.g., keep it under 1MB, allow up to 3MB on desktop browser).

We do intend to lower the amount of data returned for lower-speed connections and mobile browsers.

Comment: This really depends on your application and the amount of processing you do. If you have 1MB of data where each byte corresponds to a visual element, forget about it. If you have 1MB of data that is aggregated into a pie chart with 10 elements, no problem.

Comment: The [original d3 paper](http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2011-D3-InfoVis.pdf) ran some performance tests but focused on fps. What type of data are you using? Can you not aggregate/roll up on the server side and lazy load more detailed records as and when needed?

Comment: You might also want to look at the [dc.js library](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) which uses crossfilter to handle large datasets efficiently.